# Equation of a plane when I have two lines

Tags: geometry

How do I determine the equation of a plane if I have two lines with the following equations:
$$d_1:\:\frac{x-1}{7}=\frac{y-3}{3}=\frac{z+2}{5}\:$$
$$d_2:\:\frac{x}{7}=\frac{y+2}{3}=\frac{z-1}{5}$$

Comment: But in this case the direction vectors of the lines are parallel so you will need to find another direction vector parallel to the plane by using two points from the lines.

Comment: You should convert the lines to parametric form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a non-zero vector between two points in $d_1$. For instance take $A_1=(1,3,-2)$ and $B_1=(8,6,3)$. The vector joining $A$ to $B$ is 
$v=(7,3,5)$ (these are the denominators, do you understand why ?).
You will find that this vector is also a vector for $d_2$, so the two lines are parallel and distinct ($A_1$ is not a point of $d_2$). To define the plane containing $d_1$ and $d_2$ you need another vector that can be the vector joining $A_1$ to $A_2=(0,-2,1) \;\in d_2$. This vector is $w=(-1,-5,3)$. For any point of coordinates $M=(x,y,z)$ in the plane, the vectors  $v=\overrightarrow{A_1B_1}$,  $w=\overrightarrow{A_1A_2}$  and $\overrightarrow{A_1M}$ are coplanar, therefore the determinant
$$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}7&-1&x-1\\3&-5&y-3\\5&3&z+2\end{array}\right|=0.$$
This gives the equation of the plane as $(9+25)(x-1)-(21+5)(y-3)+(-35+3)(z+2)=0$ or after simplifications
$$ 17x-13y-16z-10=0.$$

Comment: Shouldn't $w$ be $(-1,-5,3)$ instead?

Comment: @cr001. Yes, it's true, I've mixed up the coordinates. This should be correct now.

Comment: Check the independent term. $(1,3,-2)$ must verify the equation.

Comment: I keep getting $$ 17x-13y-16z-10=0 $$ I tried using the other line as well and I get the same result.

Comment: @MikhaelM. This was a sign error in my calculations. Thanks for your comment !

Answer (score 1):

The linear combination $\lambda d_1+(1-\lambda)d_2$ describes a pencil of lines containing $d_1$ and $d_2$, i.e. a plane, as they are parallel.

You need to eliminate $\lambda$ from

$$\lambda\frac{x-1}7+(1-\lambda)\frac x7=\lambda\frac{y-3}3+(1-\lambda)\frac {y+2}3=\lambda\frac{z+2}5+(1-\lambda)\frac {z-1}5,$$ which simplifies to

$$\frac{-\lambda+x}7=\frac{-5\lambda+y+2}3=\frac{3\lambda+z-1}5.$$

Then expressing $\lambda$ two ways by solving two equations,

$$\lambda=\frac{7y-3x+14}{32}=\frac{5x-7z+7}{26}.$$

This is an equation of the requested plane, or

$$-17x+13y+16z+10=0.$$

Comment: Nice solution !

Answer (score 0):

You get $(7,3,5)$ for free and you also have two points $(1,3,-2)$ and $(0,-2,1)$ so another vector would be $(1-0,3+2,-2-1)=(1,5,-3)$

Now just take the cross product and you are good.